# Dismiss Immersive Bubble Android

Tags: android

I have entered Immersive Full Screen mode in Android. I want to disable the pop up ( Immersive bubble ) that comes on top of the screen. It is hindering my UI automation. Is there any way to dismiss it?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no you can't dismiss it. If you're after why, this answer on another thread does a great job of explaining the situation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20309721/3474528

Comment: Is there a way to detect whether the Immersive Bubble is shown or not?