# Reminder bubble in Immersive mode appearing every time after locking and unlocking the device

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm using immersive mode in my application to launch app in fullscreen mode using this code in OnCreate.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions =   View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

The app is working fine but the problem is reminder bubble("Swipe down from the top to exit full screen") which keeps on coming after i lock and unlock the screen in less than 5 sec delay.I know it is defined specifically by the developers in ImmersiveModeConfirmation class in onPowerKeyDown method.

Link:https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/ImmersiveModeConfirmation.java

Is there any way to disable this reminder bubble programatically in third party applications?

Comment: This has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075041/immersive-mode-instructions-reappear-every-time-the-device-enters-this-mode